# Jasmine + TypeScript, не могу найти метод withArgs() класса Spy

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

[Cогласно документации Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html) у объекта Spy есть метод withArgs()

```
spyOn(someObj, 'func').withArgs(1, 2, 3).and.returnValue(42);
```

Я не могу найти данный метод в версии адаптированной для TypeScript. Я создал проект Angular с использованием angular-cli (ng new), настройка работы с Jasmine предоставлена из коробки. При попытке вызова метода withArgs() Visual Code пишет что данного метода не сущестувует в типе Spy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы смотрите документацию для третьей версии Jasmine. В angular-cli используется [вторая](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json#L79).

С документацией для второй версии можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html), а с тайпингами для неё – [тут](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L616).